# List All MS Hotfixes / KBs C#

Tags: c#

Is there a quick way to to list all hotfixes / KBs? I see this but not sure where to find the dll to use it. Is there another way to get this information?

```
var updateSession = new UpdateSession();
var updateSearcher = updateSession.CreateUpdateSearcher();
var count = updateSearcher.GetTotalHistoryCount();
var history = updateSearcher.QueryHistory(0, count);

for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    Console.WriteLine(history[i].Title);
```

Comment: Project > Add Reference > COM tab > select "WUAPI 2.0 Type Library".  Add `using WUApiLib` to the top of your source code file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not have an interop library, you can use `dynamic` to access it by ProgID:

```
dynamic updateSearcher = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Microsoft.Update.Searcher"));
var count = updateSearcher.GetTotalHistoryCount();
var history = updateSearcher.QueryHistory(0, count);

for (int i = 0; i < count; ++i)
    Console.WriteLine(history[i].Title);
```

The interface is listed as being present in WUAPI.idl on the MSDN page, so another option would be to compile it with `midl` and reference the generated tlb (Add Reference > COM).

@HansPassant points out that the tlb is preregistered as "WUAPI 2.0 Type Library", which eliminates the need to manually compile the idl.

Comment: I am using .net 3.5. Getting compile error "One or more types required to compile a dynamic expression cannot be found"

Comment: `dynamic` requires .net 4 or above.  You can still add a COM Reference to use the library.